# Material UI Hidden Overflow in Material UI Design

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, next.js, material-ui

In my design with Material UI, the overflowing part of the card is absolute, but it is hidden, what could be the reason. Thanks.

my listbox  is below

```
  const Listbox = styled('ul')(
    ({ theme }) => `
  width: 100%;
  margin: -1px 0 ;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid ${theme.palette.primary.main};
  border-top: 0;
  background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#141414' : '#fff'};
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  z-index: 1;

  & li {
    padding: 5px 12px;
    display: flex;

    & span {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }

    & svg {
      color: transparent;
    }
  }

  & li[aria-selected='true'] {
    background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#2b2b2b' : '#fafafa'};
    font-weight: 600;

    & svg {
      color: #1890ff;
    }
  }

  & li.${autocompleteClasses.focused} {
    background-color: ${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#003b57' : '#e6f7ff'};
    cursor: pointer;

    & svg {
      color: currentColor;
    }
  }
`,
  );
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNJw4.png)

I created absolute postion element bu proble is persist

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that can reproduce your problem?